# Is there a way to stop BeautifulSoup from removing leading spaces?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup in a project and noticed that it removes leading spaces.
For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sample = " Test"
soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, features="lxml")
[s.extract() for s in soup(["style", "script", "[document]", "head", "title"])]
print(soup.getText(strip=False))
```

Returns "Test"

I tried setting the strip option to "False" but it did not help and I cannot find any discussion of this behavior anywhere. This is a MWE but the goal is to take HTML-formatted input and print the plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the leading whitespace, you can use `html.parser` instead of `lxml` as your parser:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

---

See the BeautifulSoup documentation on [using different parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers):

> But if the document is not perfectly-formed, different parsers will
> give different results...